# Git ignore committed files

Tags: git, directory, ignore

I have small but burdensome problem.
In my private git repository I added temporary/cache folder to push and now any time my cached files supplications in pushes. How to set them ignore?

I've try to set /temporary/cache in .gitignore file but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically if you read the git documantation, you will see tht gitignore is not the place for files that has been added to source control

> The purpose of gitignore files is to ensure that certain files not tracked by Git remain untracked.
>   To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use git rm --cached.

it is possible to use the exclude file in the .git/info/ folder to ignore files that are part of the repo but git will treat them as unchanged.